# Run script with loop with different combinations of arguments using python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate of another question but I've read other threats that attempt to use multiprocessing and I have to say it only made me more confuse (I'm a biologist attempting to deal with lots of data and files in a server and I'm not very familiarized with the proper language. My bad!).

What I basically want is to run a loop inside a script simultaneously 5 times so I can take advantage of the fact that I have several CPUs in a server. This would be simple if I didn't have different combinations of arguments as input for this script. The script loops through files (different samples in my experiment) in my folder, creating output names based on the names of these files, and modifying a string that I submit to os.system to run a program. In my program call, I also need to specify a different reference file for each one of my samples and I was doing that by building a dictionary inside my script.

I call my script like this:

```
run_ProgramXPTO.py list.txt
```

Where in list.txt I have something like this, which specifies the path to a reference file for each sample file. Let's say I have 5 samples, so I would have:

```
sampleA /path/to/reference/lion.reference
sampleB /path/to/reference/cat.reference
sampleC /path/to/reference/tiger.reference
sampleD /path/to/reference/cow.reference
sampleE /path/to/reference/dog.reference
```

Then, inside this script, I add necessary extensions to sample names, create an output name and set an argument with path to reference. My call of this program would be:

```
do_this_for_me -input sampleA_call.vcf.gz -reference /path/to/reference/lion.reference -output sampleA_call.stats
```

I was trying to use multiprocessing to make this loop run 5 times in simultaneous, but what is happening is that the same input file is running 5 times, instead of the program running 5 times with different input files. So, I'm doing something wrong and did not understand how to use multiprocessing from searching the web...

So, this is what I have so far inside my run_ProgramXPTO.py:

```
import sys
import os
import glob
import multiprocessing

#this reads a file with paths to references
list=sys.argv[1]

#this makes a dictionary from the input file where for each sample
#I now have a path to another file (reference) in my system
def make_PathDir(list):
    list=open(list,"r")
    mydir={}

    for line in list:
        row=line.strip().split('\t')
        key=row[0]
        value=row[1]
        mydir.setdefault(key,value)

    return mydir

#call the program specifying, for each input, an output name
#and the path to reference file 

def worker(x):

    for i in x:
        name1=i.strip("./")
        name2=name1.strip("_call.vcf.gz")
        output=str(name2+"_call.stats")

        path=PathDir.get(name2)

        command="bcftools stats -F %s -s - %s > %s" % (path, name1, output)

        os.system(command)

    return

PathDir=make_PathDir(list)


#and here, run my program 5 times for each input file
if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        f=glob.glob("./*_call.vcf.gz")
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker,args=[f])
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you run each test 5 times if you're just overwriting the output of the first 4 runs with `> output`?

Comment: I'm not (intentionally, at least). For each input file has its own output file. What I want to do is run the programa for each input file at the same time. The output of that program will be different for each input.

Comment: Your code says "run my program 5 times for each input file". So, you just want to process each `*_call.vcf.gz` file once and in parallel?

Comment: Ohh I see... That's where my mistake is then. I don't want to run in 5 times for each input file. I want it to run 5 times, each time with a different input file. "So, you just want to process each *_call.vcf.gz file once and in parallel?". Exactly! I want "Run my program 5 times with 5 different input files in parallel". A process for each input file.

Comment: Do you have python3 or does it have to be python2?

Comment: @Harvey I have python3, although I'm not as familiarized with it.

Comment: Python 3 is not that different from Python 2, and it comes with additional and better features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Python 3.2+ solution (I missed the Python 2.7 tag). If it has to be Python 2, we can modify this. This should give you the idea in the meantime. It replaces some of your code with the easier, more Pythonic ways of doing them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import os
import glob
import argparse
import functools
import concurrent.futures
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as PoolExecutor


NUM_CONCURRENT_WORKERS = 5


def process_sample(sample_to_reference_map, input_filename):
    """Run bcftools stats on input_filename using the correct reference file"""

    sample_basename = input_filename.rstrip('_call.vcf.gz')
    output_filename = '{}_call.stats'.format(sample_basename)
    reference_filename = sample_to_reference_map[sample_basename]
    command = 'bcftools stats -F {} -s - {} > {}'.format(
        reference_filename,
        input_filename,
        output_filename)
    os.system(command)


def process_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog=sys.argv[0])
    parser.add_argument('sample_map')
    return parser.parse_args()


def main():
    args = process_args()

    # Read sample to reference mapping
    with open(args.sample_map) as f:
        sample_to_reference_map = dict(line.strip().split() for line in f)

    # Create a worker function that has the map passed to it
    worker = functools.partial(process_sample, sample_to_reference_map)

    # Use a pool of workers to process samples
    with PoolExecutor(max_workers=NUM_CONCURRENT_WORKERS) as executor:
        # Get a list of sample files to process
        input_files = glob.glob('*_call.vcf.gz')
        # Queue a background job for each file, and keep a job-to-sample
        # map for status
        future_to_sample = {executor.submit(worker, f): f for f in input_files}
        # Print messages for each as they finish
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_sample):
            print('{} completed'.format(future_to_sample[future]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Feel free to ask questions for things you may not understand.

Comment: Yep! It works! :) I still have a lot to learn!! Thank you very much! Can I change NUM_CONCURRENT_WORKERS to another number, to run more processes/input files in parallel?

Comment: Yes, `max_workers` defaults to `5 * num_cpus` for the thread pool and `num_cpus` for the process pool: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures . I chose to use the thread pool executor because your workers immediately run a new process so there's no advantage to python spawning new processes just to then spawn another process. You can completely remove the max_workers option to get the defaults.